# SQL Queries Performance Comparison Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to compare the performance of two SQL queries i.e. stats, runtime etc.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer platform with Oracle 11g Database.

SQL Query:

```
select 
* 
from 
(select 
  countries.country_name, sum( profits.amount_sold) 
from 
  PROFITS 
full outer join 
CUSTOMERS on PROFITS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID 
full outer join 
  COUNTRIES on CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY_ID = COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID 
WHERE 
  COUNTRY_NAME = 'Japan'   
group by 
  countries.country_name )
```

Alternative query:

```
select countries.country_name, sum(profits.amount_sold)
from profits, customers, countries
where profits.cust_id = customers.cust_id
and customers.country_id = countries.country_id
and countries.country_name = 'Japan'
group by countries.country_name;
```

Could you please guide me which tools/function I can use to determine above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the execution plan: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601

Comment: The two queries are not the same.  Why are you using `full outer join` in the first but only inner joins in the second?

Comment: If you change the FULL OUTER joins to inner, it's exactly the same query (old vs. new join syntax) and should produce the same plan. Btw, based on the WHERE-condition it's no FULL but two RIGHT joins.